# Why do websites caution against external links?

Tags: phishing

I have seen it in multiple websites like **Steam** or **Hackerrank**. When I click an external link, it redirects to a new page and gives a warning like,

> You are about to visit an external link, proceed with caution

Is it to prevent phishing or is it some kind of pagerank retaining trick?

Comment: This may also be for legal / liability reasons.

Comment: its basically a disclamer saying that they are not responsible for what happens at someone elses  website.   They want you to know that while they may link it to you it is not theirs.